# Can I get a list of less variables from Javascript?

Tags: less

My requirement is as follows:

I have a file with a list of less variables. When the user changes certain inputs, the value of these variables needs to be updated.

I know I can update the value using **less.modifyVars**. But I need to know the names of all variables to do this.

Is there a way I can get a list of all the less variables in a file via JS?

Comment: See [Less Plugins](http://lesscss.org/usage/#plugins-list-of-less-plugins) and `variables-output` in particular.

Comment: Also note that if you use `less.modifyVars` to set all of these variables you don't need any Less file with these variables at all. Thus a more efficient way to handle all this would be to move all variables from this less file to your script once and forever and stop duplicating the same data.